# How to set up Windows Web Server 2008 R2 for MVC Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, setup-deployment

What I am looking for and seem unable to find, it's late and I'm tired, is a step by step guide on how to set up windows 2008 server to run asp.net mvc applications.

I am a web applications developer, amongst other things, and can do that bit fine. Normally I let someone else, like the hosting company, worry about the setup and just publish using 1-Click with web deploy or ftp.

However, for this projects I have a local Windows Web Server 2008 R2 installed but I don't know how to set it up to run the application. the deploy works, all the files arrive in the correct folder on the server, but can I get it to work?

No.

Hence the question.

For your information the app is built using Sharp Architecture, MVC3 and Razor and targeted at .NET 4 which is installed on both my development PC and the server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing would be to **download** [Windows Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and select the options you want, for example, .NET 4, MVC3 etc etc ...

Then, remember to **enable** ASP.NET in your IIS (under Roles or something...).

Comment: Done all that, still no joy, hence the plea for a step by step guide. I'm sure that there's one on the Internet somewhere, it's just a question of finding it!

Comment: you need nothing else, just what I have pointed out. what error are you getting?